# Python: 'ModuleNotFoundError' when trying to import file from same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Running Python 3.10. I have three files in the same directory named Chess, one of which is a `__init __.py` to make sure it's considered a module.

In one file, ChessMain.py I have a line:
`from Chess import ChessEngine`

When I run the file, I get the
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Chess' error.`

Sorry if this is a dumb import question, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you try `from .Chess import `

Comment: try `import ChessEngine` without the `Chess` parent

Comment: It depends on how and where you are calling your script. Right now, Python looks for a module `Chess` and try to import. If you are running inside `Chess `, then that folder|module doesn’t exist and thus error. Either call your script outside `Chess`,`cd .. && python Chess/ChessMain.py` Or use set `PYTHONPATH` to tell Python where it should look

Answer (score 2):

If they are in the same directory then you should be able to import a class or function from the file based off of its name:

```py
from Chess import <class-name>
```

If that doesn't work, you can try (as others have said):

```py
from .Chess import <class-name>
```

Or you can try:

```py
from sys import path
path.append(<absolute-path-to-your-directory>)
from Chess import <class-name>
```

The first example worked fine for me in python 3.7.3.

Comment: It is recommended not to messy with `sys.path`. Use `PYTHONPATH=path\to\directory python main.py`

Comment: but sometimes you don't have control over environment variables.

Answer (score -1):

[This Might help](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Let's say, this is my directory content

```
\_ module_1.py
\_ module_2.py
\_ main.py
```

And if I want to import it into my **main.py** file, I simply use

```
import module_1
```